# TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'find'

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I follow actually a training in nodejs, express and mongo.

I developed a rest webservice but when I try to access it, I have the current exception :

**TypeError: Object # has no method 'find'**

I don't understand what's happen exactly because my code seems correct and the same that in the tutorial.

**Schema Definition**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var bookModel = new Schema({
   title:{
       type:String
   },
    author:{type:String},
    genre:{type:String},
    read:{type:Boolean,default:false}

});

module.export= mongoose.model('Book',bookModel);
```

**Definition of my service**

```
var express = require('express'),
mongoose = require('mongoose');


var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/bookAPI');

var Book = require('./models/bookModel');

var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var bookRouter = express.Router();

bookRouter.route('/books')
    .get(function(req,res){

    Book.find(function(err,books){
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        else
            res.json(books);
    });

});

app.use('/api', bookRouter);

app.get('/',function(req,res){

    res.send('welcome to my api 2000');
})

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Running on PORT: ' +port);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var Book= mongoose.model('Book',bookModel);
```

export **module** like this:

```
module.exports = {
    Book: Book
};
```

And import with following code:

```
var Book = require('./models/bookModel').Book;
```

after that write find query

```
Book.find({},function(err,books){
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        else
            res.json(books);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks chirag, your solution works. Could you tell me why my import and export doesn't work correctly.